# Why is slicing a string not working if step is not mentioned?

Tags: python, string, slice

I am studying slicing in strings using the slicing operator `:`.

The string I have chosen is `word = 'fabricated'`.

According to me, the output for the below statements:

```
print(word[5:-8])
print(word[-3:-9])
```

should be:

```
cir
tacirb
```

However, nothing is getting printed on running these statements.  Neither on Google Colab nor on VS Code.

But when I specifically mention the `step` parameter as follows:

```
print(word[5:-8:-1])
print(word[-3:-9:-1])
```

I get my expected output as:

```
cir
tacirb
```

I would like to understand why I am getting a string of length `0` although the `step` parameter is not mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you note, the step size is not mandatory, but it defaults to `None`. In particular, `word[5:-8]` is equivalent to `word[slice(5, -8)]` or `word[slice(5, -8, None)]`.

When `word.__getitem__` gets such a slice, it treats `None` the same as `1`. (I suspect most `__getitem__` implementations would, but they don't *need* to.) When the step size is positive, you only get a non-empty string if `start < stop`, regardless of the signs involved. When the step size is negative (i.e., when a negative step is explicitly provided), then a non-empty string is produced if `stop < start` (again, independent of the signs involved).

Answer (score 2):

It's not mandatory, but it defaults to going forward, not backward, and it won't automatically flip its direction based on the endpoints. If the end comes before the beginning, and the step is positive, the slice will be empty.

It's simpler to understand if you translate the negative indices to their positive equivalents.  Start with your `[5:-8]` example:

```
>>> word = 'fabricated'
>>> word[5:-8]
''
>>> word[5:-8:-1]
'cir'
```

A negative index is just treated as if you'd added it to the `len` of the sequence, so for this 10-letter `word`, an index of `-8` is equivalent to an index of 10 - 8 = 2:

```
>>> len(word)
10
>>> word[5:2]
''
>>> word[5:2:-1]
'cir'
```

Obviously, 2 comes *before* 5 when you're counting up.  The only way to get from 5 to 2 is to count *down* (i.e. the `step` slice parameter must be negative).

Answer (score 0):

By default, slices begin at the starting index and proceed *forward* in the sequence until the ending index is reached.

If the ending index is larger than the starting index, it will *not* infer that the direction ought to be backwards.  It still defaults to *forwards*.

Answer (score 0):

String slicing follows below rules-

> **sequence [start:stop[:step]]**

**start**
(Optional) = Starting index of the slice. Defaults to 0.
**stop**
(Optional) = The last index of the slice or the number of items to get. Defaults to len(sequence).
**step**
(Optional) = Extended slice syntax. Step value of the slice. Defaults to 1.

| f | a | b | r | i | c | a | t | e | d | <= sequence elements |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | <= positive indexes |
| 10 | -9 | -8 | -7 | -6 | -5 | -4 | -3 | -2 | -1 | <= negative indexes |

word fabricated will be represented as [0:9:1]

From the above table-
when slicing as **word[5:-8])** becomes **word[5:-8])** = **word[5:-8:1])**. From the table you will move right to left and since step is positve its movement will be from left to right. Here we have movement in different direction, hence no char will be taken into consideration.

When slicing as **word[5:-8:-1])** from the table for 5:-8 movement will be in right to left and step movement will also be from right to left. Here we have movement in same direction therefore you got the result.

For more information check this [string slicing](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html)